# Launching Multiple Screen Commands through python

Tags: python, python-3.5

I have multiple python files to run. How would I launch all those files within one .py script? This is what I came up with but it shows the screen action and really doesn't begin the other stuff unless I exit out of it. Here's the code, not much:

```
import os 

print("Launching Bot, just for you.")
print("Loading up shard 0")
try:
    os.system("screen python3.5 run_0.py > /dev/null")
except:
    print("Shard 0 failed")
print("Loading up shard 1")
try:
    os.system("screen python3.5 run_1.py > /dev/null")
except:
    print("Shard 1 failed")

print("Done running shards...")
```

I was doing some research and they said to use subprocess but when I used it, it didn't run my command properly. (I don't have a copy of that code, I lost it).

The problem is that I want to run the python script and it works fine but I have to close the screen to start the other one and I just want it to run the command w/o showing the output. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `import subprocess` in a python file. You can then start other instance of other programs with :

```
subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "newprogram.py"])
```

You can mix that with `multiprocessing` package to launch one thread by new program

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target= mp_worker , args=( ))
p.start()
```

where `mp_worker` launches the other program.

Comment: I'll tesf it out when i get home

Comment: Hi, can you be more specific with the multiprocess or more detailed?

Comment: Could you provide an examples with screen?